# Case statement appears to not check all combinations

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am having an issue with this case statement not checking the combinations of defined variables. I tried to troubleshoot the issue by process of elimination and discovered that they work individually but not in the group. So my question is does anyone see any errors or have any suggestions to otherwise tackle this?

```
switch (true)
{
    case pv131 != 'LAB.CMC1' && pv134 == 'XYZ' && obr21 == 'MISC2':
    case pv131 != 'LAB.CMC2' && pv134 == 'XYZ' && obr21 == 'MISC2':
    case pv131 != 'LAB.CMC3' && pv134 == 'XYZ' && obr21 == 'MISC2':
    case pv131 != 'LAB.CMC4' && pv134 == 'XYZ' && obr21 == 'MISC2':
    case pv131 != 'LAB.CMC5' && pv134 == 'XYZ' && obr21 == 'MISC2':
    msg['MSH']['MSH.8']['MSH.8.1'] = '12345678';
    break;
}
```

Thank you - Matt

Comment: Why are you even using a `switch`? It would be easier to read and understand if it was just `if (pv134 === 'XYZ' && obr21 === 'MISC2' && ['LAB.CMC1','LAB.CMC2','LAB.CMC3','LAB.CMC4','LAB.CMC5'].indexOf(pv131) === -1) ...`.

Comment: You are not using the switch statement correctly.  The switch statement is used to evaluate possible values of one variable. You can't have multiple operators like you do in the case statements. Sounds like you want multiple if statements.

Comment: @DavidP It works fine syntactically, it's just a weird usage

Comment: @Mike I was using switch as there are other combinations I have to check for as well. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what was suggested, the following is a working solution:

```
case ['LAB.CMC'].indexOf(pv131) === -1 && pv134 === 'XYZ' && obr21 === 'MISC2':
msg['MSH']['MSH.8']['MSH.8.1'] = '12345678';
break;
```

I was also able to reduce the repetition by only having to check for 'LAB.CMC'.